# What's an elegant way to filter an object with an array list for empty elements and sort it in preferred order? (Javascript, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Dialogflow cloud function that gets a parameters object from an user input.

When I type in Dialogflow: "I am working in the garden" it basically creates this parameters object:

```js
var parametersObject = {
    nouns: ["garden"],
    pronounsDefinite: ["I"],
    verbsHelpPresent: ["am"],
    articles: ["the"],
    verbsGerund: ["working"],
    prepositions: ["in"],
    verbsInfinitiv: [],
    adverbsTime: [],
};
```

Now my plan is to write all the necessary data to Firebase in some kind of order.
I would like to filter all parameters with this array list here, which also gives my preferred order:

```js
var listOfParameters = [
    "pronounsDefinite",
    "verbsInfinitiv",
    "verbsGerund",
    "articles",
    "nouns",
];
```

and then create a new list of non empty objects with the order from my listOfParameters:

```js
var listOfNonEmptyObjects = [];
```

This listOfNonEmptyObjects is then written to Firebase.

Right now I add all the objects to listOfNonEmptyObjects like this:

```js
try {
    const pronounsDefinite = agent.parameters.pronounsDefinite[0];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({ "pronounsDefinite": pronounsDefinite });
} catch (error) { }
try {
    const pronounsDefinite1 = agent.parameters.pronounsDefinite[1];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({"pronounsDefinite1":pronounsDefinite1});
} catch (error) {}
try {
    const verbsInfinitiv = agent.parameters.verbsInfinitiv[0];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({ "verbsInfinitiv": verbsInfinitiv });
} catch (error) { }
try {
    const verbsGerund = agent.parameters.verbsGerund[0];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({ "verbsGerund": verbsGerund });
} catch (error) { }
try {
    const articles = agent.parameters.articles[0];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({ "articles": articles });
} catch (error) { }
try {
    const nouns = agent.parameters.nouns[0];
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({ "nouns": nouns });
} catch (error) { }
```

So I get this:

```js
listOfNonEmptyObjects = [
    { pronounsDefinite: "I" },
    { verbsGerund: "working" },
    { articles: "the" },
    { nouns: "garden" },
];
```

I also set "ignoreUndefinedProperties: true" which leaves out empty elements (In this case verbsInfinitiv which has no value).

Is there a more elegant way, maybe with a forEach function that looks up every entry in listOfParameters, then checks if parametersObject has a non empty element and after that adds it to the listOfNonEmptyObjects?

Edit: I added an example what happens if for example the pronounsDefinite parameter contains more than one element (e.g. pronounsDefinite: ["I", "You", "He", "She"],), so if the user puts in several words that match the pronounsDefinite entity. Then I would get this parameter as **pronounsDefinite1** in my try catch block.

Comment: `nouns: ['garden']` this array will always contain a single element?

Comment: Just iterate over `listOfParameters`, see if that key exists and is a non empty array and add it to `listOfNonEmptyObjects`.

Comment: nouns can also contain more elements, depending on the user input.

Comment: Can you modify the example to show how the program should behave then?

Comment: Yes, I would get the parameter as pronounsDefinite1 in my try catch block and look for the index [1] at agent.parameters.pronounsDefinite[1] to get the second entry in the array if there is one.

Comment: I modified my code to consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take with after learning from boxdox's solutions:

```js
var parametersObject = { nouns: ['garden','a random addition for testing'], pronounsDefinite: ['I'], verbsHelpPresent: ['am'], articles: ['the'], verbsGerund: ['working'], prepositions: ['in'], verbsInfinitiv: [], adverbsTime: []}
var listOfParameters = ["pronounsDefinite", "verbsInfinitiv", "verbsGerund", "articles", "nouns"];

var listOfNonEmptyObjects = [];

// Let's go through each of the listed parameters
listOfParameters.forEach( parameter => 
  // If such a parameter exists in parametersObject, handle each one of its values.
  (parametersObject[parameter]||[]).forEach((item, index) => 
    // Push each value as an object into the list of non empty objects
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({[parameter+(index?index:'')]: item})
  )
);

console.log(listOfNonEmptyObjects);
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. I've learned something new. Thank you and all others for helping me out!

Comment: I'm sorry, I came back and removed the reduce() from the code. ForEach is simpler and I realized that the outer reduce is unnecessary after all, because I am mutating the listOfNonEmptyObjects with push(), so there is no need for passing the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the `listofParameters` first. Then for each parameter, you need to check if the parameter exists in `parametersObj`. You can do this using the `in` operator. In that same if condition, you can also check if the value of `parametersObj` is empty or not. If both conditions are met, you can then push the value into your `listOfNonEmptyObjects`

```
var listOfNonEmptyObjects = []

listOfParameters.forEach(parameter => {
  if (parameter in parametersObject && parametersObject[parameter].length > 0) {
    listOfNonEmptyObjects.push({[parameter]: parametersObject[parameter]})
  }
})
```

---

### Completely Unrelated

You can use Filter and Map. Object.entries converts the object into a tuple of key and value. Then you can filter the empty value (ie, second element of tuple). Finally you can map over and construct your desired array

```
Object.entries(parametersObject)  // Split the parameters object into an array of key-value pairs.
  .filter(([k, v]) => v.length)   // Accept only non-empty parameters by checking the parameter array length.
  .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v[0]})) // Convert each key-value pair in the array into an object.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't quite understand your solution. How can I iterate over listOfParameters, see if that key exists and is a non empty array and add it to listOfNonEmptyObjects (like Salman A said above)?

Comment: @Finn I guess I misread your question. Let me make an edit